# Centroids of triangles in parabola

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Two perpendicular lines intersect at $O = (0, 0)$. One of the lines intersect parabola $y^2 = 3x$ at some point $G$, the other one intersects this parabola at $H$. Find equation of the set of all centroids of triangles $OGH$. $G$ and $H$ are different from $O$.

Answer (score 1):

A line passing through $O$ has equation $r:y=mx$ and intersects the parabola $y^2=3x$ at point $O$ and $G\left(\dfrac{3}{m^2};\;\dfrac{3}{m}\right)$

The perpendicular has equation $s:y=-\dfrac{1}{m}\,x$ and intersects the parabola at $O$ and at point $H(3m^2;\;-3m)$

Therefore the centroid of triangle $OGH$ has coordinates $P\left(\dfrac{x_O+x_G+x_H}{3};\;\dfrac{y_o+y_G+y_H}{3}\right)$

that is $P\left(m^2+\dfrac{1}{m^2};\;\dfrac{1}{m}-m\right)$

The parametric equations of the locus are

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 x=m^2+\dfrac{1}{m^2} \\
 y=\dfrac{1}{m}-m \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

$y^2=m^2+\dfrac{1}{m^2}-2$

The equation of the locus is

$y^2=x-2$

Hope this is useful

Comment: Hmm, you where faster. Never mind, I not going to delete my solution know. :)  +1

Comment: @JohnWatson *were. You surely are not the John from 221B!

Comment: Of course I am. And what does that to do with mathematics or especially for this problem?

Comment: @JohnWatson This is the way I am earning a living for $40$ years :)

Answer (score 1):

So we have a line $y=kx$ which intersect a parabola at $G({3\over k^2}, {3\over k})$ and a line $y=-{x\over k}$ which intersect a parabola at $H(3k^2, -3k)$.

So the center of gravity is $$T({1\over k^2}+k^2, {1\over k}-k)$$

So $$y^2 = ({1\over k}-k)^2 = {1\over k^2}-2+k^2 = x-2$$